# Dynamically pull an image out of content to put in the href for fancy box

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have a gallery page on the website I'm working on and I can't touch the HTML for the most part including the images. I put fancy box onto the page because I want the images to pop after clicking the thumbnails. Here is what my css looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="lightbox" href="#">
         <img src="images/gal1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a> 
</div>
```

in order to get this structure I had to add this bit of script:

```
$('.col-sm-8 img').addClass('img-responsive');
$('.col-sm-8 img').wrap('<a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="lightbox" href="#"></a>');
$('a.thumbnail.fancybox').wrap('<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>');
$('div.col-sm-4.col-xs-6.col-md-3.col-lg-3').wrapAll('<div class="list-group gallery"></div>');
```

This all works great except for the image pop -  because of the way fancy box works it needs the image link in the `href` of the anchor tag wrapped around the thumbnail. Is it possible to select the image in the content and place it in the `href` making it look like this effectively:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="lightbox" href="images/gal1.jpg">
             <img src="images/gal1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </a> 
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet should do what you asked.

```
$('a.thumbnail').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).attr('href', a);
});
```

Edited to match your comment.